# Can't link my javascript file in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started working with Rails and I spent all day trying to figure out this issue. I made a javascript file that I placed inside of the javascript assets folder, my application.js is also untouched yet I can't get it to link to my html file. The code itself works fine because if I put it within a `<script>` element it executes.

application.html.erb

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding this under my head element within the other html file where I'm trying to get the js to work.

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application'%>
```

The issue is in the js file itself.  The script works fine using a `<script>` but when using the javascript include tag it comes up with a
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
The error comes from the line

```js
links[activeLink].classList.add("active");
```

..

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".itemLinks");
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

// the activeLink provides a pointer to the currently displayed item
var activeLink = 0;

// setup the event listeners
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.addEventListener('click', setClickedItem, false);

    // identify the item for the activeLink
    link.itemID = i;
}

// set first item as active
links[activeLink].classList.add("active");

function setClickedItem(e) {
    removeActiveLinks();

    var clickedLink = e.target;
    activeLink = clickedLink.itemID;

    changePosition(clickedLink);
}

function removeActiveLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
}

// Handle changing the slider position as well as ensure
// the correct link is highlighted as being active
function changePosition(link) {
    var position = link.getAttribute("data-pos");

    var translateValue = "translate3d(" + position + ", 0px, 0)";
    wrapper.style[transformProperty] = translateValue;

    link.classList.add("active");
}

//
// Dealing with Transforms
//
var transforms = ["transform",
            "msTransform",
            "webkitTransform",
            "mozTransform",
            "oTransform"];

var transformProperty = getSupportedPropertyName(transforms);

// vendor prefix management
function getSupportedPropertyName(properties) {
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        if (typeof document.body.style[properties[i]] != "undefined") {
            return properties[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected your source code in the browser to see what it's actually returning to you? Also should check your network tab in Chrome devtools and be sure your pathing is correct and that the js is loading. If it's not attempting to load the js at all, that would tell me that your script tag is not coming back as you expect.

Comment: This could be any number of things, and without some sort of information on what kind of response you're getting, it's hard to tell.  You'll need to provide information about whether you're getting any response, a 404, and empty .js file, a silent failure, or what.

Comment: @gravityplanx There are no errors going on the screen.  The javascript file is for a content slider.  So it just rotates between photos.  When I try to load it by making a call from the js file directly, it does not work(pictures don't rotate).  When I use the <script> element directly in my html file it works fine.

Comment: @Brian FitzGerald I don't know what you mean by using the dev tools to make sure that the file is being loaded.

Comment: Hey @EddieBeazer using the Chrome browser you have access to "devtools" which allows you to dynamically inspect the code that is returned to the browser: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQKvro1Wz-E

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip with chrome.  I was able to find an issue with the script itself and updated the problem.  That is going to be one useful tool to use.